# Is there a way to turn down the verbosity of MIT Scheme?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I recently decided to start playing with MIT Scheme by following along with the examples in SICP. I installed scheme from the Ubuntu repository.

```
sudo apt-get install mit-scheme
```

Given an input file that looks like this:

```
486
(+ 137 349)
(- 1000 334)
(* 5 99)
(/ 10 5)
(* 25 4 12)
```

I run scheme as follows.

```
scheme < Numbers.scm
```

It produces the following output.

```
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Sunday February 7, 2016 at 10:35:34 AM
  Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116

1 ]=> 486
;Value: 486

1 ]=> (+ 137 349)
;Value: 486

1 ]=> (- 1000 334)
;Value: 666

1 ]=> (* 5 99)
;Value: 495

1 ]=> (/ 10 5)
;Value: 2

1 ]=> (* 25 4 12)
;Value: 1200

1 ]=> 
End of input stream reached.
Moriturus te saluto.
```

This output feels excessive, so I'm currently paring it down like so.

```
scheme < Numbers.scm  | awk '/Value/ {print $2}
486
486
666
495
2
1200
```

**Is there a native way to reduce the verbosity of scheme, so I can get something resembling the above output without resorting to an external process?**

I have examined the output of `scheme --help` but did not find any obvious options.

---

Note that passing the filename as an argument does not appear to work in MIT-Scheme.

```
scheme Numbers.scm  
MIT/GNU Scheme running under GNU/Linux
Type `^C' (control-C) followed by `H' to obtain information about interrupts.

Copyright (C) 2011 Massachusetts Institute of Technology
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Image saved on Sunday February 7, 2016 at 10:35:34 AM
  Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118 || Edwin 3.116
;Warning: Invalid keyword: "Numbers.scm"
;Warning: Unhandled command line options: ("Numbers.scm")

1 ]=>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
scheme --quiet < Numbers.scm
```

Now this will suppress the REPL entirely except when errors occur so that what is not explicitly displayed will not be displayed. eg. evaluatiing `(+ 2 3)` returns `5`, but does not print since you have not told it to print. You need to use procedures like `display` to get the information printed or go back to using a REPL which sole purpose is to display your results.

I was originally hoping you could do:

```
scheme --quiet --load Numbers.scm
```

But it does not exit after the file and adding `--eval (exit)` has the REPL ask if you want to quit.

**EDIT**

```
(define (displayln v)
  (display v)
  (newline)
  v)

(displayln (+ 4 5))
; ==> 9, in addition you get the side effect that "9\n" is written to current output port
```

You could also perhaps make a macro to do this:

```
(define-syntax begin-display
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ form ...) (begin (displayln form) ...))))

(begin-display
  486
  (+ 137 349) 
  (- 1000 334)
  (* 5 99)
  (/ 10 5)
  (* 25 4 12))
; ==> 1200. In addition you get the side effect that "486\n486\n666\n49\n2\n1200\n" is written to current output port
```

Comment: For completeness, please show the modification to `Numbers.scm` needed to actually display output under this mode.

Comment: I had to use `(display (string-append (number->string 486) "\n"))` to display the value of an expression on its own line but if you have something simpler, I'd love to learn it.

Comment: @merlin2011 I've added some examples. Note that since `displayln` returns its argument you can use it anywhere. Eg. `(+ (displayln (* 4 5)) 34) ; ==> 54, but 20 is also printed`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround,

```
scheme < Numbers.scm | gawk '/^;Value: / { sub(/^;Value: /, ""); print }'
```

But maybe you'd run it as a script file rather than an stdin stream? Not sure about MIT Scheme invocation, something like

```
scheme Numbers.scm
```

Though this way you'll have to print out the results explicitly, with `(display)` or something, otherwise they'll go unnoticed.

Comment: It looks like the passing the filename as an argument doesn't work for this version of scheme; please see update to question.

Comment: `scheme -f Numbers.scm`? `man scheme`, then `/script` or `/file`? I don't have it installed, so I can't help you here.